# linked list missing element

Tags: c, linked-list, element

I am writing a c program where I want to add strings to a linked list based on a condition. As my code is rly long I made a simplified version which also shows my problem.

My problem is that after filling the list with strings, when I want to print all the elements, my "go_thru" function fails to print the last element of the list.
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct listelement{
    char val[100];
    struct listelement *next;
} LISTELEMENT;

void go_thru( LISTELEMENT *head ){
    LISTELEMENT *temp = head;

    while( temp != NULL ){
        printf("%s ", temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

LISTELEMENT *insert_before( LISTELEMENT *head, char value[] ){
    LISTELEMENT *new_el = ( LISTELEMENT* ) malloc( sizeof( LISTELEMENT ) );

    strcpy( new_el->val, value );
    new_el->next = head;

    return new_el;
}

int main()
{
    LISTELEMENT *list_chi = NULL;
    int i;
    char arr[6][10] = { "cheese",
                        "salt",
                        "icecream",
                        "snow",
                        "summer",
                        "violet"    };
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        list_chi = insert_before( list_chi, arr[i] );

    go_thru( list_chi->next );

    return 0;
}
```

The output contains all the strings except "violet". I google-d a lot, looking for an answer, even tried to search here btw the questions, but still could not manage to solve the problem :/

Comment: `go_thru( list_chi->next );` skips the first node (containing the last inserted element, `"violet"`). Use `go_thru(list_chi);` to print all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the for-loop in main finishes, your list looks something like:

```
"violet" -> "summer" -> "snow" -> "icecream" -> "salt" -> "cheese" -> [NULL]
/* where -> is a 'next' */
```

(The reverse ordering is due to the use of `insert_before`.) With that in mind, the problem is:

```
go_thru(list_chi->next); /* ERROR: skips first element! */
```

Why? Well, to use that diagram again:

```
   "violet"    -> "summer"      -> "snow" -> "icecream" -> "salt" -> "cheese" -> [NULL]
/* ^^ list_chi    ^^ list_chi->next */
```

You can fix that by calling `go_thru(list_chi)` instead. Other than that, your code looks good.

Comment: wow, it works, thank you mate. I got a little confused about the "head" and "next" stuffs after not being able to solve the problem on my own. but all clear now. such an easy solution. sorry for spamming with the question.